# How do I display my sample list in Meteor.js? What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm learning JavaScript and Meteor.js and I cannot get my list of ToDo's to display in the browser. I copied strait from the meteor tutorial site just to see how it worked and if I can get something to display on the screen. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?
My Code:

```
**main.css**

/* CSS declarations go here */
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #315481;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #315481, #918e82 100%);
    background-attachment: fixed;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: white;
}

header {
    background: #d2edf4;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d0edf5, #e1e5f0 100%);
    padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
    position: relative;
}

#login-buttons {
    display: block;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

form {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    position: relative;
}

.new-task input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 80px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.new-task input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
}

.delete {
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: #eee solid 1px;
}

li .text {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

li.checked {
    color: #888;
}

li.checked .text {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

li.private {
    background: #eee;
    border-color: #ddd;
}

header .hide-completed {
    float: right;
}

.toggle-private {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    li {
        padding: 12px 15px;
    }

    .search {
        width: 150px;
        clear: both;
    }

    .new-task input {
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
}


**main.html**


<head>
    <title>simple</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
        {{#each tasks}}
            {{> task}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
</body>

<template name="task">
    <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>


**main.js**

import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './body.html';

import '../imports/ui/body.js';

Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: [
        { text: 'This is task 1' },
        { text: 'This is task 2' },
        { text: 'This is task 3' },
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Meteor! And great job familiarizing yourself with the framework by following the tutorial.

Based on the code you provided there seems to be a couple issues that need to be corrected. Let me talk you thru them.

Lets start with you template files (html files).  It looks like you have a couple defined in one single file. The issue here is you forgot to define your main temple fir your todo list.  I have corrected this below.

**main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>simple</title>
</head>

<template name="taskList">
  <div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
        {{#each tasks}}
            {{> task}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="task">
    <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

Its also important to point out that you do not need to include your `<head>` element​ in your template definitions. Leave these out like I show above.  Meteor will know how to deal with it.

Now lets look at your JavaScript. First, you need to make sure you import your template and css files correctly (this assumes all your files are in the same directory).

Next, you need to define your `tasks` template helper using the Template object that matches your template name in your html file (taskList). This helper is just a function that returns some test data.  Later you can change it to return a collection cursor.

**main.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './main.html';
import './main.css';

Template.taskList.helpers({
    tasks: function() {
      return [
        { text: 'This is task 1' },
        { text: 'This is task 2' },
        { text: 'This is task 3' },
      ];
  },
});
```

With these changes you should be good to go. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Body is a not template. You need to create a template and reference that inside body.

```
<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
     <ul>
        {{#each tasks}}
            {{> task}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

//js
Template.main.helpers({
    tasks: [
        { text: 'This is task 1' },
        { text: 'This is task 2' },
        { text: 'This is task 3' },
    ],
});
```